# Scratch 1.4 not available on Ubuntu 13 anymore?

Tags: apt, software-center

I used to run older versions of Ubuntu that included Scratch 1.4.

I have a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 (installed today) and Scratch is just not there anymore. The Software center does NOT show any Scratch in its search results, plus the link to the debian/ubuntu installation [here](http://scratch.mit.edu/scratch_1.4/)  fails to work.

Is this because we are expected to use Scratch 2.0? Scratch 1.4 is useful to us in a number of situations. I would only like to understand if there is a way to get it back on the new Ubuntu. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I just opened apt:scratch from your linked page, and it opens software-center with the scratch app, and shows version 1.4.0.6 as being available, and I'm on 14.04, and the package is synced from Debian. If you aren't seeing it in search results, then perhaps you don't have the `universe` repository enabled or something.

Comment: The question is clear and it's not a bug. Why should someone vote to close such question?!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just do this(I don't think there us a problem in software center). You just seem that you are not enabling the universe repoisoty.

But please be sure you enable the universe repository(if it's enabled skip this step). To enable universe repository do this

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install scratch:

```
sudo apt-get install scratch
```

Anyway if you like to install the binary(.deb) directly you can download:

[scratch1.4 32bit](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scratch/scratch_1.4.0.6~dfsg1-2_all.deb) or [scratch1.4 64bit](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scratch/scratch_1.4.0.6~dfsg1-2_all.deb) according to your needs.

Now you have the .deb file you can install by the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/scratch*.deb
```